# Why a segmentation fault here?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

GDB gives me the following information:

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x0000000100000a3f in minHeapify ()

For reference, graph is an array of pointers.

```
//all info for a vertex
typedef struct Vertex{
    float key;
    struct Vertex *prev;
    float loc[4];
} Vertex;

//using the pointer
typedef Vertex *VertexPointer;

VertexPointer *
createGraph(int numpoints, int dimension){
    //seed the psuedo-random number generator
    srand(time(NULL));

    //declare an array for the vertices
    VertexPointer *graph = malloc(numpoints * sizeof(*graph));

    //create the vertices in the array
    int x;
    int z;
    for(x = 0; x < numpoints; x++){
        //create the vertex
        VertexPointer v;
        v = (VertexPointer)malloc(sizeof(Vertex));
        (*v).key = 100;
        //(*v).prev = 0;
        //multiple dimensions
        for(z=0; z < dimension; z++){
            (*v).loc[z] = rand_float();
        }
        //put the pointer in the array
        graph[x] = v;
    }
    return graph;
} 


void
extractMin(VertexPointer *graph, int size){
    printf("We've stepped into extractMin");
    (*graph[0]).key = 100;
    minHeapify(graph, size, 1);
}




void
minHeapify(VertexPointer *graph, int size, int i) { 
    printf("We've stepped into minHeapify");
    //get the indexes of the left and right children.  readjust indices to start at 0.
    int l = 2i -1;
    int r = 2i;
    i = i - 1;

    //following the algorithm on p. 154 of CLRS  
    int smallest;
    if((l < size) && ((*graph[l]).key < (*graph[i]).key) ){
        smallest = l;
    }
    else{
        smallest = i;
    }
    if( (r < size) && ((*graph[r]).key < (*graph[smallest]).key) ){
        smallest = r;
    }
    if(smallest != i) {
        float exchange = (*graph[i]).key;
        (*graph[i]).key = (*graph[smallest]).key;
        (*graph[smallest]).key = exchange;
        minHeapify(graph, size, smallest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not setup remote debugging?

Comment: This cannot be answered without seeing how `VertexPointer *graph` is created. Nobody knows what graph is pointing to from the code you posted.

Comment: @Daniel Daranas I've posted more code.

Comment: @devnull what is remote debugging?  sry, new to this

Comment: @hannah It was a hint to suggest that the information appears to be insufficient to provide an answer.

Comment: What input for `createGraph()` and `extractMin()` causes this code to crash?

Comment: If error catchable under debugger, why not just examine backtrace and variables values? (my bet is that graph is NULL within function call, and that `2i` construction isn't what it supposed to mean here). And - just curious - is it some kind of riddling joke to use `(*...)` instead of `->` operator?

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose this without more hints. I'd suggest to you to execute the bt command at the GDB prompt immediatelly after the SEGFAULT message and post the results with your answer, things'll get much easier then.

Comment: `VertexPointer *graph` this is a pointer to pointer to vertex according to your def. so `(*graph[0]).key = 100;` has to be `(*graph[0])->key = 100;`rest of your code will have to be changed.

Comment: @tesseract - No, `graph` is a pointer to a pointer to a `vertex`; `graph[0]` is a pointer to a `vertex`; `(*graph[0])` is a `vertex`. So what is there is correct.

Comment: hannah, I see you have safeguards that check for l and r against size.  Please also add a check in the start of minHeapify that checks to make sure i is less than size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely reason for the crash is in your index adjustment: First time around, you adjust `i` from `1` to `0`. However, in subsequent calls, you fail to adjust upward again, so e.g. if `i` is the smallest element first time around, the second call has `i = -1`. That adjustment code makes it rather hard to reason about the correctness of your algorithm.

Another problem is that you mistyped `2*i` as `2i`.

A third problem is that it’s not enough to swap keys for the algorithm to deliver a correct result, you’ll have to swap the whole vertices (or, actually, their pointers).